# Count Specific date as one 1 word

Tags: php

I have many dates. The format is like below:

```
August 28, 2016 at 09:20AM
August 28, 2016 at 09:20AM
August 28, 2016 at 09:26AM
August 28, 2016 at 09:26AM
August 28, 2016 at 09:26AM
```

I want the result is like this:

```
August 28, 2016 at 09:20AM = 2
August 28, 2016 at 09:26AM = 3
```

Every line is separate with new line (enter in keyboard). How can I achieve that?

Comment: http://ideone.com/NVUGhZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in an array and do this:

```
array_keys(array_count_values($array));
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
    $s = 'August 28, 2016 at 09:20AM
August 28, 2016 at 09:20AM
August 28, 2016 at 09:26AM
August 28, 2016 at 09:26AM
August 28, 2016 at 09:26AM';
    $s = explode(PHP_EOL, $s);
    $s = array_count_values($s);
    var_dump($s);
    print_r($s);
?>
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  ["August 28, 2016 at 09:20AM"]=>
  int(2)
  ["August 28, 2016 at 09:26AM"]=>
  int(3)
}
```

```
Array
(
    [August 28, 2016 at 09:20AM] => 2
    [August 28, 2016 at 09:26AM] => 3
)
```